# If A→(B∧C), Prove (D→A) → (D→C) without using conditional proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

The conditional proof version of this is pretty easy. However, solving this without conditional proof seems to be quite difficult.

I tried to turn the premise into:

1. ~A v (B∧C)
2. (~AvB) ∧ (~AvC)

I tried to use disjunction introduction to transform (~AvC) into (D→A) → (D→C) but failed.

Any ideas on how should I proceed? Maybe disjunction introduction is not the right way to deal with this problem?

Comment: How are $D$ and $H$ connected with $A$, $B$ and $C$?

Comment: Second that question, what is D and H?

Comment: Sorry, made a typo. H should be C.

Comment: still, hwat is D?

Comment: D is just D. Therefore I think we need to introduce D by using disjunction introduction.

Comment: What is a "conditional proof"?

Comment: Also, $(D\supset A)\supset (D\supset C)$ doesn't make sense: $D\supset A$ and $D\supset C$ are not sets.

Comment: You can set (D⊃A) and show that (D⊃A) ⊃ (D⊃C). Conditional proof means you can assume something is true and use that to derive something else. In this case, (D⊃A) leads to (D⊃C).

Comment: Huh... I just realized → is more commonly used as implication. I changed the symbols now. Hopefully it makes sense.

Comment: @fkraiem A conditional proof consists of some derivation which starts with a hypothesis and then discharges that hypothesis by use of conditional introduction.

Comment: @fkraiem - the symbol $\supset$ as a *connective* is still used in math log textbook; see : Jan von Plato [Elements of Logical Reasoning](https://books.google.it/books?id=QrdEAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA9) (2013).

Answer (score 0):

1) $A \to (B \land C)$ --- premise

2) $\lnot A \lor (B \land C)$ --- from 1) by [Material implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference))

3) $(\lnot A \lor B) \land (\lnot A \lor C)$ --- from 2) by [Distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property)

4) $(\lnot A \lor C)$ --- from 3) by [Conjunction elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_elimination)

5) $(\lnot A \lor C) \lor \lnot D$ --- from 4) by [Disjunction introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_introduction)

6) $[(\lnot D \lor C) \lor D] \land [(\lnot D \lor C) \lor \lnot A]$ --- from 5) using : $[(\lnot A \lor C) \lor \lnot D] \equiv [(\lnot A \lor C) \lor \lnot D] \land TRUE$ and : $TRUE \equiv (D \lor \lnot D) \lor C$ and [Associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property) and [Commutativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property)

7) $(\lnot D \lor C) \lor (D \land \lnot A)$ --- from 6) by *Distributivity*

8) $\lnot (\lnot D \lor A) \lor (\lnot D \lor C)$ --- from 7) by [De Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

9) $(\lnot D \lor A) \to (\lnot D \lor C)$ --- from 9) by *Material implication*

> 10) $(D \to A) \to (D \to C)$ --- from 9) by *Material implication*.

---

Of course, with *Natural Deduction* the proof is much more easier.

Comment: How did you go from step 5 to step 6? What method iis "∧TRUE"?

Comment: @JohnGao - because $P \land TRUE \equiv P$ and $P \lor TRUE \equiv TRUE$ for any $P$ (check with truth table).

Comment: See [Table of Logical Equivalences](http://integral-table.com/downloads/logic.pdf) : *Identity* and *Universal Bound*.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove this through what might get called "prefixing" CCpqCCrpCrq, which isn't too far away in terms of condensed detachment from the axiom set.

I use Polish notation.  The formation rules are:

1. All letters of the Latin alphabet are well-formed formulas.
2. If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ qualify as well-formed formulas, so does C$\alpha$$\beta$ and K$\alpha$$\beta$.

So, we want to prove CaKbc $\vdash$ CCdaCdc.

The axioms I'll use are CpCqp - Recursive Variable Prefixing, CCpCqrCCpqCpr - C-Self Distribution, CKpqq - right conjunction elimination.  I also use condensed detachment.  Note we can make substitutions for any letters, except for a, b, c, and d in the following.

```
axiom      1 CpCqp
axiom      2 CCpCqrCCpqCpr
axiom      3 CKpqq
D1.2       4 CpCCqCrsCCqrCqs
D2.4       5 CCpCqCrsCpCCqrCqs
D5.1       6 CCpqCCrpCrq
assumption 7 CaKbc
D6.3       8 CCpKqrCpr
D8.7       9 Cac
D6.9      10 CCpaCpc
```

And CCpaCpc comes as a more general well-formed formula of the special case CCdaCdc.